# How to display an array of objects in page template in Pyramid?

Tags: python, html, web-applications, web, pyramid

I have a small simple question in HTML+Pyramid.

Consider I have one table in database and I want to display all records from this table in my page template.
I know how to retrieve the data from database, but I don't know how to display them on HTML page. I know how to show one single value, for instance total number of records in a table. I can return a simple JSON on my callable view and render it. Like here:

```
@view_config(route_name='tasks', renderer='templates/tasks.pt')
def view_tasks(request):
    try:
        count = DBSession.query(MyTable).all().count()
    except DBAPIError:
        return Response(conn_err_msg, content_type='text/plain', status_int=500)
    return { 'Total' : count }
```

And corresponding HTML code:

```
...
<h3>Now ${Total} tasks are not completed</h3>
...
```

But how do I return a set of records? Or how do I show them on HTML page another way?
Any suggestions?

```
@view_config(route_name='tasks', renderer='templates/tasks.pt')
def view_tasks(request):
    try:
        items = DBSession.query(Task).all() # this is a set of objects
    except DBAPIError:
        return Response(conn_err_msg, content_type='text/plain', status_int=500)
    return { # how to display them on page tamplate??? }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using Chameleon (the .pt extension), so you'll get a lot of mileage out of reading their [documentation](http://chameleon.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference.html).

```
<table>
  <tr tal:repeat="item items">
    <td>${item.name}</td>
    <td>${item.description}</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
% if items:

% for item in items:

<table>
  <tr >
    <td>${item.name}</td>
    <td>${item.description}</td>

% endfor:

% endif:
```